# Remove code between comments with grunt uglify

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

Is it possible to remove code between special comments with grunt uglify in javascript?

For example js code like this:

Source code:

```
var that = this;
var x=y;
//REMOVE-BEGIN
that.someCodeToBeRemoved();
that.someMoreCodeToBeRemoved();
//REMOVE-END
that.someFunctionCall();
```

What should be removed:

```
//REMOVE-BEGIN
that.someCodeToBeRemoved();
that.someMoreCodeToBeRemoved();
//REMOVE-END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [grunt-strip-code](https://github.com/nuzzio/grunt-strip-code) for this.

I don't think grunt uglify can do it.

Answer (score 0):

As @marton said, grunt uglify does parse the code and optimize/compress/etc. you should go with grunt-strip-code.

Check out [http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/] to get in details what uglify does.

Comment: Ok thanks, looks like I need to do it in two steps. Piping seems not possible with grunt. I need some full code with debug code in it and some "compressed" without the debug code and typical "uglifying".

Comment: Maybe `SourceMaps` can help https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#sourcemap